# How to replace style class using mootools

Tags: css, mootools

How to replace style class with mootools.Consider,

```
<form>
<div class="form-label">
    <label>User ID</label>
</div>
<div class="form-element">
    <input type="text"  name="userid">
</div>
<div class="form-label">
    <label>password</label>
</div>
<div class="form-element">
    <input type="text"  name="password">
</div>
 </form>
```

Here, I would like to replace style class `form-label` with `form-label-new`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$$('.form-label').set('class', 'form-label-new');
```

Comment: Mark it as the right answer then so that some one can use it.